# Script to produce folder

Tags: scripts, cron

I have recently moved server from Ubuntu 14.04.1 to 18.04, gradually moving data and scripts etc.

I have a script to, each morning, make a folder in the form of a date eg 20201017 for 17th October 2020. It has worked fine on Ubuntu 14.04.1 but on 18.04 misbehaves.

```
foldername='$(date +'%Y%m%d')'
mkdir -p  /var/www/ .... /old/$foldername
```

I have also tried, and many other versions,

```
mkdir /var/www/ ...  /old/`date +%Y%m%d'
```

instead of producing 20201017 it produces '20201017'$'\r'

Any help would be most gratefully received and maybe prevent me going bald.

Comment: `$'\r'` at the end is probably due to your editor. You need to set the line-ending to Unix.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
foldername='$(date +'%Y%m%d')'
```

To this:

```
foldername="$(date +'%Y%m%d')"
```

Comment: That won't matter, really. Since the OP is running the `mkdir` command with `$foldername` unquoted, the `date` will be run when the `mkdir` runs and the right value will be returned. The problem is that the OP edited their script in Windows, see the `\r`.

Comment: Thanks to you both for answering the question.  Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have edited your script in Windows, which converted the standard UNIX line endings (`\n`) to the Windows ones (`\r\n`). You can test this with `cat -V`:

```
cat -v yourScript.sh
```

You will see something like this:

```
$ cat -v yourScript.sh
foldername='$(date +'%Y%m%d')'^M
mkdir -p  /var/www/ .... /old/$foldername^M
```

The `^M` are the `\r`, which you need to remove. The easiest way is installing `dos2unix` and running:

```
dos2unix yourScript.sh
```

Alternatively, you can do it in sed:

```
sed -i 's/\r//g' yourScript.sh
```

After that, your script should work as expected. However, you should also take the opportunity to make a small improvement and change it to:

```
mkdir -p  /var/www/ .... /old/"$(date +'%Y%m%d')"
```

There's no reason to have a separate variable for `foldername`, but more importantly, you should [*always* quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/22222). So even if you keep the second variable, use:

```
## Actually run the command now, otherwise, the foldername 
## will change if your script runs at 11:59 and takes more than a second.
foldername=$(date +'%Y%m%d')
mkdir -p  /var/www/ .... /old/"$foldername"
```